# Good way to detect ".." segments in a file path

Tags: c#, .net, path, filepath

Unfortunately there is no way to search for this kind of information, so I'll have to ask for it.

I need a way to prevent users from entering file system paths containing parent references "..". This is allowed:

- /path/to/file
- file-alone
- other/path

This is forbidden:

- /path/../file
- ../file
- ../../file
- .. /file (note the additional space)
- path/ .. /file/ ..

I can think of using a regex to catch this, or splitting the string at the path separator and comparing each trimmed part. But will this catch all possible ways to represent such a parent path (on Linux and Windows) and which is the most efficient method of them?

I don't really care about whether there are ".."s further down the path so that it won't jump above the specified root. No ".." is allowed anywhere. A user can easily resolve such references themselves, so the system doesn't have to deal with it.

Comment: `yourPath.Contains("..")`...?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann There are legale names like `foo..bar`

Comment: Under Windows I think the space is a legal character, so `..(space)` is a legal name

Comment: [iswellformeduristring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-5.0) with is absolute ?

Comment: @TaW I don't need absolute paths. In fact, in my scenario they are forbidden. I have a path prefix that's applied to all user-provided paths and the user must not escape that base directory with "..". And a URI is not a path.

Comment: @xanatos True, but I can live with excluding such confusing names.

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by splitting the paths on `/`, trimming and then look for `..`, this could look something like this:

```
var testString = new [] {
    // allowed
    "/path/to/file",
    "file-alone",
    "other/path",

        
    // Not allowed
    "/path/../file",
    "../file",
    "../../file",
    ".. /file",
    @".. \file",
    "path/ .. /file/ ..",
    @"path/ .. /file\ .."
};

foreach (var str in testString)
{
    var pathsNotAllowed = new [] { ".." };
    var isValid = !str.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar).Select(s => s.Trim()).Any(s => pathsNotAllowed.Contains(s));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Valid: {1} \t Text: {0}", str, isValid));
}
```

Output:

```
Valid: True      Text: /path/to/file
Valid: True      Text: file-alone
Valid: True      Text: other/path
Valid: False      Text: /path/../file
Valid: False      Text: ../file
Valid: False      Text: ../../file
Valid: False      Text: .. /file
Valid: False      Text: .. \file
Valid: False      Text: path/ .. /file/ ..
Valid: False      Text: path/ .. /file\ ..
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ecOP7M

Comment: He specified both Windows and Linux, so perhaps `.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)`

Comment: I don't think it should be `Contains` but rather `equals` - Windows doesn't allow spaces in the `..` component and I would assume Linux will not either, but with spaces it could be a valid filename.